# How to use GitHub in VS 2015 so a moron can understand?

Tags: visual-studio, github

Downvote if you want... but I need a set of simple basic steps that we can follow. We have VS Enterprise, no GitHub add-ons installed. We have a an empty repo created on GitHub. What do each of the developers do after that? There's a local repo, right? Should there be another project on the local machine that commits to the local repo or do we open the project in the repo? If yes, how do we create that other project? What about the .sln file that VS lovingly puts in a separate folder? We have been at this for hours and believe me we have tried every combination of commit/push/sync/goat sacrifice except the right ones. We cannot reproduce consistent results such that two developers can work against the same remote repo. Sometimes one developer can push and he doesn't see the files pushed by the other developer. Sometimes the Commit Message text box lights up but the Commit button is disabled. I thought I was reasonably intelligent until I started working with GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the broad steps you need to do. You may need to fill in a bit of the detail. THis is how I would work it. I am sure you could get many other opinions.

1. Create the repo on GitHub (which You already have done.)
2. Each developer should then go to the GitHub repo and fork the repo under their own GitHub account.
3. Each developer then needs to clone their repo to their local machine. (That's the beauty of Git. Every developer has the entire repo locally.) You can do this in VS2015 by choosing: File -> New -> Repository -> Clone.
   Go to your on-line repo and get the URL of the repo that you will be cloning. Enter it into the New Repo dialog box in VS.
4. When working on the project, each developer should create a temporary feature branch, which they push to their own GitHub repo. They can then push their work as often as they want without it conflicting with other developers.
5. When a developer thinks that their work should be merged into master, they should go to GitHub and issue a "Pull Request" for their feature branch.
6. Their PR can then be discussed among the team before it is accepted.
7. Once it is accepted and merged into master, the developer can delete their feature branch locally and on GitHub, if he likes.
8. Since "master" on the team repo has now been updated, each developer will need to pull down master from the team repo to update their own local and remote repos.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like an how-to-use git issue. You probably first need to see how two collaborators work on same project with git. I donot think either VS or GitHub has anything to do here, as both only provides you git gui tool regarding this issue.